# how to fetch data from more than one table?

Tags: mysql

I have to find out the output as name of students who have secured more than 70? My both tables are-

```
CREATE TABLE student(Fields_ID INT, Name VARCHAR(20));
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(30,'JYOTI');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(31,'KIRTI');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(32,'YOGITA');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(33,'RASHMI');
        INSERT INTO student(Fields_ID,Name) VALUES(34,'NUPUR');
SELECT * FROM student;

CREATE TABLE Marks(Fields_ID INT, Student_ID INT NOT NULL,marks INT NOT NULL);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (30,40,100);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (31,41,88);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (32,42,72);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (33,43,33);
        INSERT INTO Marks(Fields_ID,Student_ID,Marks) VALUES (34,44,15);
SELECT * FROM Marks;
```

I was trying to return the required out from the following code but i was unable to form the logic. Any idea how to do it.I am a beginner in MySql so I am unable to find out the problem.

```
SELECT student.name,(select (marks>70) from marks)
From Student INNER JOIN marks  
    ON student.Fields_ID = marks.Fields_ID
GROUP BY student.name;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check conditions for groups with the `having` clause.. Use having to check if the `sum` of the marks reached your limit for every student.

```
SELECT student.name
From Student 
INNER JOIN marks ON student.Fields_ID = marks.Fields_ID
GROUP BY student.name
HAVING sum(marks) > 70
```

Comment: but I have to return only one column of student name.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: your code returns the name of all students and checks whether they have marks more than 70 or not not by putting yes or no under the column,but I have to return only names and those names who has marks more than 70.